# Sorting in PriorityQueue regaring second item which is long or double data type in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparable

In Java if we want to sort based on second item in PriorityQueue using Comparable interface
The Code will be like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{

    public static class Pair implements Comparable{
        int node;
        int weight;
        public Pair(int node,int weight){
            this.node = node;
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            return this.weight - ((Pair)o).weight;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String [] args){
        PriorityQueue<Pair> pq = new PriorityQueue<Pair>();
        pq.add(new Pair(2,3));
        pq.add(new Pair(2,3));
    }
}
```

But, if the weight data type will be long or double how to handle for sorting priorityQueue regarding this case?

Need Help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying, weight can be an int, or a long or a double? you could use double type for weight.

Comment: It will not work because Comparable interface dont have any compateTo method which return type long or double

Comment: why are expecting long or double as return type of compareTo method. Read once here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: ok but what should i write down under compareTo method if weight data type is long or double :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{
    int node;
    Double weight;
    public Pair(int node,double weight){
        this.node = node;
        this.weight = weight;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair o) {
        return this.weight.compareTo(o.weight);
    }
}
```

Comment: my compare logic based on second [long/double] type item sorting which will be this.weight - ((Pair)o).weight but thats now working for long or double only works for int